# How to get the Maximum Intensity Projection along the surface normal in 3D

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, visualization, projection

I met a problem to calculate and visualize the Maximum Intensity Projection (MIP) along the surface normal in 3D.

The problem seems very easy if we just want to get the along one of axis, for example some simple Matlab codes,

```
% Generate sample 3D matrix
A = rand(2,2,2)
% Get maximum intensity projection.
mip = max(A, [], 3)
```

However, I am interested in get the MIP along surface normal, for example, I have got some surface and the surface normal plot looks like this:

[image]

If we imagine that the surface got some thickness with some intensities assigned, I want to get the MIP along the surface normal (NOT just along x, y or z axis).

The other example I found online is this

[image]

In (a) is some 3D rendered surface, and (b) shows the surface normal. (c) shows the calculated MIP because the 3D surface got some thickness.

I am not sure if we can achieve this in Matlab or some third party software can do this. Please give me some hints. Thanks a lot.

A.

Comment: I think that (a) and (c) could be achieved with `patch`. Take a look [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/134922-how-to-colour-a-3d-image-with-a-continuous-spectrum-of-colours)

Comment: @A_C Thanks for your reply. Yes, I think I know how to plot (a) and (c) in Matlab. Actually I am interested in plotting (c), as we need to calculate MIP at first. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Take the dot product between the surface normal and the displacement vector going from the surface point to the camera position, and divide by the product of their magnitudes to get the cosine of the angle (θ). If this is less than zero then ignore (backface culling); if between zero and one, interpolate between blue and red using this as the parameter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I believe what you are talking about do make sense, but I couldn't get my head around this. Do you have a detailed reference (like a paper or online handout) for me to look at or some pseudo-codes for me to understand this better?

Comment: @SamoJerom see diagram